# When to Take the Developer Maintenance Exam

Tags: release-exam

I took my Dev 401 on March 2, 2015 . Looking at the schedule I am little confused. When should I take the release exam to maintain my Dev 401 credential.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what release exam you have been certified .Let's say you took winter 15 then you will get an automated mail when release maintenance exams for Spring 15 will be out .

The website http://certification.salesforce.com/schedules#credential will indicate when is the last dates by which you should manditorily finish the exam and dates when exams are available.

Once exams are available you will need to log on to https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=publicHome&branding=SALESFORCE and complete the exam .

Also there will be reminder emails sent from Salesforce if you have not completed the maintenance and there is a risk of losing certification.

Look for dates on website .

[image]